# Changing view property with View Binding has no effect

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-viewbinding

I'm trying to use view binding to change the visibility of an `ImageView` in the app bar when I navigate to a certain fragment.  The structure of the app is pretty much like the stock *Navigation Drawer Activity* in Android Studio.

Since the `app_bar_main.xml` layout is included in `activity_main.xml` and has an id, I figured I should be able to just inflate the `ActivityMainBinding` and reference the app bar and its views.  So I do like in the documentation to access the binding from the fragment:

```
private var _binding: FragmentChooseVehicleBinding? = null
private var _mainBinding: ActivityMainBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!
private val mainBinding get() = _mainBinding!!
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    chooseVehicleViewModel =
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(ChooseVehicleViewModel::class.java)
        
    _binding = FragmentChooseVehicleBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        
    _mainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    mainBinding.appBarMain.appBarLogo.visibility = View.GONE  //This has no effect in the UI

    return binding.root
}
```

I checked with debugging and the visibility property on appBarLogo changed correctly and is the right value in `onStart()`/`onResume()` as well, but the image still appears in the UI.

Another thing I tried is to inflate the app bar view binding directly, like this:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val binding = AppBarMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    binding.appBarLogo.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Still no change in the UI; the image remains visible.  The only thing that works is the old findViewById:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    val appBarLogo = activity?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.appBarLogo)
    appBarLogo?.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

**Update**: Here are the layout files (thanks Michael):

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_main"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_header_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_black"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.company.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_red"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.company.PopupOverlay">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/appBarLogo"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo_company" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You haven't shown us the layout files.

Comment: Do you understand what layout inflation does? It parses the XML to create views. You're just creating a new instance of your main activity layout inside of your fragment so modifying it has no effect on views that are actually laid out by the activity. You need to keep using find by id or cast your `activity` to your main activity type so you can get the binding from there.

Comment: @Pawel I get what you're saying, but in all the documentation I've seen, a view binding is always used after calling inflate() on the view binding class.  What do you mean by "get the binding from there"?

Comment: I added a public property in the MainActivity class to save the MainActivityBinding object.  In my fragment I reference it like so:
`val mainActivity = activity as MainActivity
mainActivity.mainBinding.appBarMain.appBarLogo.visibility = View.GONE`
Is that what you meant?

Comment: if `mainBinding` is the one thats inflated and set as main activity content then yes.

Comment: Well it seems to work, thank you.  It's still not entirely clear to me where the inflation has to be done to get the one object of a binding class that will affect the UI though. For instance I have a `LoginDialog` Dialog class with its own layout that I instantiate from `MainActivity`.  The doc says I should inflate the binding class in `MainActivity`'s onCreate().  Doesn't work, I have to inflate it in `LoginDialog` itself and save it in a field, then reference that later.  Anyway I just wish the doc was more elaborate.

Comment: Inflating creates a new ViewGroup layout. What you do with it is up to you. If you want to use it as your Activity's layout, call `setContentView` with it. If you want to set it as a Fragment's view, you return it in `onCreateView`. If you want to use it for a Dialog layout, you pass it to the Dialog. You can do anything with it, but each time you inflate, you're creating a new and independent copy of the layout, and probably want to store the binding in a property, wherever appropriate.

Comment: The docs for View Binding don't really tell you anything beyond the two most common uses (Activity content view, or Fragment View), but you can use it anywhere you can use a  ViewGroup. These classes, Activity, Fragment, Dialog, ViewHolder, etc., don't know anything about view binding. They each have their own way of working with Views, so you have to look to their specific documentation to know where it's expecting you to set a ViewGroup.

Comment: Create a ViewModel for `MainActivity` and then use an observer to communicate with the MainActivity do not directly access views of the Activity in Fragment or simply create an Interface and just call the method to hide/show